# Does Nativescript using Angular2 need special a *ngFor?

Tags: angular, nativescript, ngfor

I am creating this mobile app where i have to list a few labels.
The code looks like this:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'code-m',
    template: `
                <StackLayout dock="top" orientation="vertical" style="height:90%;" backgroundColor="lightgray">
                    <label text="Code Methods" style="background-color:red;"></label>
                    <Label *ngFor="let item of items" [text]="item"></Label>
                    <label text="test" style="background-color:blue;"></label>
                </StackLayout>
        `
})
export class CodeMethodsComponent{
    public items:Array<string> = [];

    constructor(){
        this.items.push("Default");
        this.items.push("Validation");
        this.items.push("Filter");
        this.items.push("Business");
        this.items.push("Provisional");
        console.log(this.items);
        console.log("test")
    }
}
```

The label with the *ngFor does not show up at all. Feels like the loop is not working at all. I checked the documentation in Nativescript's website and it seems to have and older deprecated version(using # instead of let) which does not work either. I would really appreciate it if you could guide me through my mistake and if possible suggest me a place(other than Nativescript's website) to get help.

It is fair to mention that the first and last label are showing up correctly.

[EDIT]
It seems at `*ngFor="let item of items`  it doesn't recognize the items array. Tried extrapolating it with {{}} but got an error for doing so.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Why is the second `label` with an uppercase `L`?

Comment: Just tried having it lowercase. same result, nothing. I should add that I have also tried using <ListView> (pretty much copy pasted the tutorial) and even that wouldn't show up( ListView should've appeared since i copy pasted the code and the data from the tutorial)

Comment: Well, it looks like you're missing the directives in your component annotation. So after `selector: 'code-m',` try putting `directives: [StackLayout],` and maybe even add `Label` to that array, if that is NativeScript specific.

Comment: It gives me a `JS: Error: Uncaught (in promise): No Directive annotation found on Label` . Same for StackLayout too. I am pretty sure they should work fine without any imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this problem was an incorrect implementation of the router.

I was routing to this component from my main component using an onClick router.navigate(). Routing this way, don't know why, seemed to route correctly to the destination,it would create any static labels/buttons/etc. but not any that are depended on *ngFor(even *ngIf wouldn't work).

In summary , using a [nsRouterLink] for navigation  instead of router.navigate() fixed my code.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the given example and found that you should use `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`, which to allow  `view`  to trigger all changes, when new values has been pushed in the array. You could also review the example below.

`app.component.html`

```
<StackLayout dock="top" orientation="vertical" style="height:90%;" backgroundColor="lightgray">
        <label text="Code Methods" style="background-color:red;"></label>
        <Label *ngFor="let item of items" [text]="item"></Label>
        <label text="test" style="background-color:blue;"></label>
</StackLayout>
```

`app.component.ts`

```
import {Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
    public items:Array<string> = [];

    constructor(){
        this.items.push("Default");
        this.items.push("Validation");
        this.items.push("Filter");
        this.items.push("Business");
        this.items.push("Provisional");
        console.log(this.items);
        console.log("test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Just done that but no luck. I have added `<Label *ngIf="items" text=" The arrayexists"></Label>` to my code to check if my array exists and it seems it doesn't. But why ?

Comment: Could you provide some more info the problem or to sent  me sample project, which could be debbuged. I have just tested my suggestion on clear nativescript angular project and it works correctly. However you could use `ListView` as Manijak suggested and you could find examples in nativescript docs - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html#list-view

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how your data looks like in the list, but try this with the repeating label:

```
<Label *ngFor="#item of items" [text]="#item"></Label>
```

or

```
<Label *ngFor="#item of items" [text]="#item.someproperty"></Label>
```

UPDATE: Same example shown here from the official documentation
https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html#using-an-item-template

Comment: Both give me identical errors to this:
`JS: "#" inside of expressions is deprecated. Use "let" instead!`
`Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#item.toString] in CodeMethodsComponent@9:51`

Comment: Same example shown in the official documentation https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/list-view.html#using-an-item-template